# modify headers add-on mobile browser

Tags: android, browser, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, firefox-addon

Browser like Firefox and chrome when installed on PC have modify headers add-on to modify and use the custom http headers into the http request.

Do we have any same/similar feature/application when we access firefox/ chrome browsers present/installed on (Android)Smart Phones ?

Basically, I want a way to be able to set custom http request headers in smart phone mobile browsers to fetch the intended page from server.  Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Fiddler to modify http requests, and the following link helps you [Configure Fiddler for Android](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) and [Modifying a Request or Response](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse).

As for chrome-extension support for mobile, the answer is no, [Official FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/faq) has mentioned that.

> Does Chrome for Android support apps and extensions?
>
> Chrome apps and extensions are currently **not supported on Chrome for Android**. We have no plans to announce at this time.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox browse on Android the way you do it is exact same way you do it on Firefox for PC. The same code works, you just have to enable the addon to work for Android by adding to the manifest file basically `android:true`. Here is an addon for Firefox on Android that changes the user agent - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/search/?q=user+agent&appver=&platform=

Here is the first addon on that list - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/custom-user-agent-string/?src=search

Answer (score 0):

We cannot add ad-ons on a mobile browser and modify headers easily. There are applications in play store using which HTTP requests can be made by manipulating headers

Comment: Hello @aayansh, do you know any such application (a tried and tested one) for this purpose?